# Are there any algorithms or bit hacks for counting the occurrence each nth bit over an array of integers?

Tags: c++

I have a lot of 32b values and I need to count the occurrence of each nth true bit over the entire length of the data and I need to do it as fast as possible because this is the performance bottleneck of the whole simulation. I created a naive c++ approach that does this for 8 bit values to illustrate the question:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <cstdint>

std::vector<uint32_t> vertical_popcount(std::vector<uint8_t>& data) {
    std::vector<uint32_t> result({0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0});
    for (auto i = 0; i < data.size(); i++) {
        result[0] += (data[i] & 0b10000000) > 0;
        result[1] += (data[i] & 0b01000000) > 0;
        result[2] += (data[i] & 0b00100000) > 0;
        result[3] += (data[i] & 0b00010000) > 0;
        result[4] += (data[i] & 0b00001000) > 0;
        result[5] += (data[i] & 0b00000100) > 0;
        result[6] += (data[i] & 0b00000010) > 0;
        result[7] += (data[i] & 0b00000001) > 0;
    }
    return result;
}

int main() {
    std::vector<uint8_t> data({0b00000001, 0b00000100, 0b00000101});
    auto result = vertical_popcount(data);
    std::cout << "occurrence of bits: " << result[0] << ", " << result[1] << ", " << result[2] << ", " << result[3] << ", " << result[4] << ", " << result[5] << ", " << result[6] << ", " << result[7] << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

Is there an algorithm that does the same but (much) faster?

Comment: The book [Hacker's Delight](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hacker%27s_Delight) by Henry S. Warren, Jr is full of an enormous amount of curated bit twiddling algorithms.  Including a fast way to do [std::popcount](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/popcount).

Comment: Are your input bit vectors sparse (few 1s) or dense (few 0s)?

Comment: @Botje on the average around 30% 1s

Comment: @SupportUkraine my example is in c++ but either is fine

Comment: @Eljay Oh nice, didn't know std had popcount out of the box. Updated my example (got rid of compiler intrinsic)

Comment: Is it intentional that your example code enumerates the bits from most-significant to least?  That's the reverse of what I would ordinarily expect, and it does not extend naturally to wider inputs.

Comment: @JohnBollinger it is not intentional, either way of enumerating is fine by me

Comment: @JohnBollinger It felt more logical to me to do it this way for me. Bit 63 at the front, Bit 0 at the end, so that the bit with lowest value is then always counted at array index 0. I think its like those big-endian, little-endian thing... just what you're used to

Comment: Are you using gcc?  If so, you have `__builtin_popcount` available to you.

Comment: To clarify, your sample code counts bits in each position of eight-bit bytes, but you want an algorithm to count bits in each position of 32-bit words? If so, I expect this has been asked on Stack Overflow previously.

Comment: @EricPostpischil I made the sample code use 8 bit data units as opposed to 32 only for the sake of brevity since it is trivially adaptable to 32 bits. However, what I'm looking for is indeed a fast algorithm that counts the total of each nth true bit of 32b data units, yes.

Comment: @PepijnKramer On PPC the bits are numbered differently from what everyone else is using. Confused the hell out of me when I had to read specs.

Comment: If there is no way to improve the speed of the actual bit checking logic, then it may be worth noting that the loop iterations can be run in parallel. OpenMP with a reduce clause for the sums will probably give you an almost linear speed up in the number of available CPU cores. Parallel algorithms from std could also be used, you just need to ensure that the summation is done independently (without race condition or need for a lock) per thread.

Comment: I'm too busy rn to formulate this into a real answer but I ended up doing this: I looked for a number that when multiplied and masked would expand the space between relevant bits. Brute force got me to 129, 16513, 2113665, I noticed the pattern which took me to 567382630219905. So now I split the input into bytes, multiply, mask and shift the bytes to 32b int sets, add them together 255 at a time and extract byte values. Overall this processes the data fast enough(~1TB/s) that it bottlenecks at the memory bandwidth of the 3080Ti I'm using.

Answer (score 2):

Pepijn Kramers answer shows how to parallelize the operations to do 8 byte at once. My answer looks at doing more bits at once.

In your code you extract each bit and increment a counter. You do a SIMD operation on that manually on blocks of 8 uint64_t.

The idea is to spread the bits out alternating 0 and data bits so that they can be added without overflowing into the next data bit. First step is to spread them out into 2bit units, then 4bit units, 8bit units and then sum the bytes in each uint64_t. If you want to extend this to 32 bit counts then you need to add 2 more steps to separate into 16bit units and 32bit units. The example below works on 8 uint64_t but if you have larger arrays you can merge more values per step. Just keep track of how many bits you have for each count (2, 4, 8, 16, 32) and don't merge more than `2^n-1` values.

```
uint64_t data[8] = 0x0123456789ABCDEF;

static const uint64_t mask0 = 0x5555555555555555;
static const uint64_t mask1 = 0x3333333333333333;
static const uint64_t mask2 = 0x0F0F0F0F0F0F0F0F;

// split even and odd bits and add 2 values together
// 2 bit per count, max value 2
uint64_t t000 = data[0] & mask0 + data[1] & mask0;
uint64_t t010 = data[2] & mask0 + data[3] & mask0;
uint64_t t020 = data[4] & mask0 + data[5] & mask0;
uint64_t t030 = data[6] & mask0 + data[7] & mask0;
uint64_t t001 = (data[0] >> 1) & mask0 + (data[1] >> 1) & mask0;
uint64_t t011 = (data[2] >> 1) & mask0 + (data[3] >> 1) & mask0;
uint64_t t021 = (data[4] >> 1) & mask0 + (data[5] >> 1) & mask0;
uint64_t t031 = (data[6] >> 1) & mask0 + (data[7] >> 1) & mask0;

// split into nibbles and build sum of 4 values
// 4 bit per count, max value 4
uint64_t t100 = t000 & mask1 + t010 & mask1;
uint64_t t101 = t001 & mask1 + t011 & mask1;
uint64_t t102 = (t000 >> 2) & mask1 + (t010 >> 2) & mask1;
uint64_t t103 = (t001 >> 2) & mask1 + (t011 >> 2) & mask1;
uint64_t t110 = t020 & mask1 + t030 & mask1;
uint64_t t111 = t021 & mask1 + t031 & mask1;
uint64_t t112 = (t020 >> 2) & mask1 + (t030 >> 2) & mask1;
uint64_t t113 = (t021 >> 2) & mask1 + (t031 >> 2) & mask1;

// split into bytes, and build sum of 8 values
// 8 bit per count, max 8
uint64_t sum[] = { t100 & mask2 + t110 & mask2;
                   t101 & mask2 + t111 & mask2;
                   t102 & mask2 + t112 & mask2;
                   t103 & mask2 + t113 & mask2;
                   (t100 >> 4) & mask2 + (t110 >> 4) & mask2;
                   (t101 >> 4) & mask2 + (t111 >> 4) & mask2;
                   (t102 >> 4) & mask2 + (t112 >> 4) & mask2;
                   (t103 >> 4) & mask2 + (t113 >> 4) & mask2; }
// add 8 bytes of sum[i] into a single byte
for(int i = 0; i < 8; ++i) {
    sum[i] = sum[i] & 0xFFFFFFFF + (sum[i] >> 32);
    sum[i] = sum[i] & 0xFFFF + (sum[i] >> 16);
    sum[i] = sum[i] & 0xFF + (sum[i] >> 8);
}
```

Unless I made a mistake `sum` should now hold the bit count for each bit 0-7 for the block of 8 uint64_t.

You can improve this for larger blocks. When the bits are split into even and odd each count has 2 bits. That can hold the sum of 3 uint64_t and I only use 2. Similar the split into nibbles has 4 bits per count so it can hold the sum of 15 uint64_t. The split into bytes can hold the sum of 255 uint64_t.

You can also extend this to SIMD registers and do 128bit - 512bit at once. And I think there is a SIMD sum of bytes in vector intrinsic you can use instead of the loop at the end.

Comment: same issue as other answer. 8 bit example was just demo. OP has 32bits to count.

Comment: That just means it needs 2 more steps of masking and adding. The idea remains the same.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a sketch of a possible approach (you can improve on this a lot if you can tweak your input to multiples of 8 bytes, or if you know the size of your vectors up front). But it gives you an idea how to use popcount. (For 32bits architecture the pattern is the same but you get less performance)

```
// #include <intrin.h> // for popcnt which counts number of set bits in a variable
#include <array>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <cstdint>
#include <memory>


// work on copy on purpose so we can pad memory of vector to 64bit alignment (kind of a quick hack for now, the extra memory (re)allocations might slow you down too much)
auto vertical_popcount(std::vector<std::uint8_t> values)
{
    // use 64bit architecture to do 8 values per cycle
    static constexpr std::array<std::uint64_t, 8> masks
    {
        0x0101010101010101,
        0x0202020202020202,
        0x0404040404040404,
        0x0808080808080808,
        0x1010101010101010,
        0x2020202020202020,
        0x4040404040404040,
        0x8080808080808080
    };

    //using an array instead of vector safes at least one dynamic allocation
    std::array<std::size_t, 8> counts{};

    // align data to multiple of 8 bytes
    // add a few extra 0 bytes, they wont impact the counting
    for (std::size_t n = 0; n < values.size() % 8; ++n)
        values.push_back(0);

    // make a uint64_t pointer into 8 bit data
    // to pickup 8 bytes at a time for masking
    auto ptr = reinterpret_cast<std::uint64_t*>(values.data());
    for (std::size_t n = 0; n < values.size() / 8; ++n)
    {
        for (std::size_t m = 0; m < 8; ++m)
        {
            // mask 8 bytes at a time
            auto masked_value = (*ptr & masks[m]);
            
            // count bits of 8 uint8_t's in one loop
            auto bitcount = std::popcount(masked_value);
            counts[m] += bitcount;
        }
        ++ptr;
    }

    
    return counts;
}

int main() 
{
    std::vector<uint8_t> data({ 0b00001001, 0b00000100, 0b00000101 });
    auto result = vertical_popcount(data);
    std::cout << "occurrence of bits: " << result[0] << ", " << result[1] << ", " << result[2] << ", " << result[3] << ", " << result[4] << ", " << result[5] << ", " << result[6] << ", " << result[7] << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `popcount` is now part of C++20: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/popcount

Comment: Hehe yes just found out :) Update example accordingly. If pre C++20 then a compiler intrinsic like __popcnt64 could still be used

Comment: Did you make measurements that it is in fact faster? Compilers optimalizator is quite smart and often code work better without this `reinterpret_cast` hacks.

Comment: @MarekR To be honest I did not (and mostly had a bit of fun thinking of how I would do it manually). But you are absolutely right, measurement should be part of accepting this as a solution. And I already know that the extra allocations I do in std::vector are not helping. But at least I could have looked using compiler explorer to check the generated assembly for both solutions. Me bad ;)

Comment: Masking so that `popcount` will only count the selected bits of each byte will give some speedup for counting 8 bytes at a time using 64-bit words. However, OP wants to count bits within 32-bit words, so this masking can only count two at a time (from two 32-bit words within a 64-bit object). There are better solutions.

Comment: According to [QuickBench](https://www.quick-bench.com/q/zM5GpDhFOz4GHvupQ93lcKKhKv0) this is slightly faster than the naive solution. However I think the results are [not the same](https://godbolt.org/z/59Y68Tjec)

Comment: @EricPostpischil Yes propably something like AVX512 + popcnt

Comment: @perivesta Wrong output would be bad indeed.  I don't have time to troubleshoot, but I'll leave this solution here since I think I can learn a thing or two fro your QuickBench info. Thanks for that!

Comment: @perivesta it is nice that you have provided performance test. But after couple tweaks in test itself [gain is much more significant](https://www.quick-bench.com/q/49ki5Y_XUozFMMFKaZX-ro72GNE).